# Proving a lemma from the fundamental theorm of finite abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Hello I'm trying to prove the following lemma from FTOFAG.

[image]

The textbook solution is the following:

[image]

I am trying to figure out the highlighted part. Why is $x^{sm} \in H$ and $x^{tp^n}
 \in K$?? And Lagrange's Theorem Corollary $4$ states 'Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $ a \in G$. Then, $a^{|G|} = e$. How does this have to do with getting to the highlighted part?

[image]

As of the second part of the prove, why is $p^nm = |HK|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(x^{sm})^{p^n}= x^{sp^nm} = (x^{|G|})^s = e^s = e $, so $x^{sm} \in H$ by definition. The exact same argument shows that  $x^{tp^n} \in K$ .

Edit: To answer your second question, $|HK| = |G| = p^nm$.